# Strange device appears in xinput

Tags: mouse, input

I have been noticing this problem ever since I installed MATE. Whenever I boot up my computer my mouse always moves to the top of the screen quickly (like if someone plugged in a second mouse and I have to wrestle with it).

I looked at lshw and found nothing out of the ordinary, but with xinput I  found this odd entry:

```
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

I disabled it and the problem is gone. I checked my computer and found no physical device plugged in that could be causing this. So my question is what is causing this problem?

Thanks for any help.